# How to rewrite url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

How can I rewrite a URL in codeigniter

For example, I would like to rewite this URL:

```
http://greenville.homes.sc/dev/demo_greenville/Community/Simpsonville/Stonewyck
```

To something like this:

```
http://greenville.homes.sc/dev/demo_greenville/Simpsonville/Stonewyck
```

Comment: Have a read of URI Routing - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

If `users` is the controller and `community` is the function:

```
$route['users/Simpsonville/Stonewyck']   
       = "users/Community/Simpsonville/Stonewyck";
```

You want to re-route the abbreviated URL ('users/Simpsonville/Stonewyck') to the full URL ('users/Community/Simpsonville/Stonewyck')

Set this in the following file: `application/config/routes.php`

**Footnote:**
Depending exactly on what you are trying to achieve, you may also want to add:

```
$route['Simpsonville/Stonewyck']   
       = "users/Community/Simpsonville/Stonewyck";
```

It all depends if you want to hide both the controller and the function name/segments.

If these parameters are variable, you may also need to use something like:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)']   
       = "users/Community/$1/$2";
```

Comment: no , my controller is users and my function name is community. so it's not working

Comment: What is your default controller? `user`? and also, what is the setting for your `base_url`?

Comment: my default controller is users. and my function name is community. And base_url = dev/demo_greenville.

Comment: I suggested something else... please review.

Comment: `Simpsonville` and `Stonewyck` should probably be variable and not hardcoded into his routes, but yes, this is basically how you should do this.

Comment: @Mischa I added a footnote based on your comment, thank you.